# What is the replacement for $q.when, $q.defer & defer.promise in Angular 6 using Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-promise

I'm upgrading from Angularjs to Angular 6,In AngularJS they are using Promises and some $q functions, I couldn't find the replacement for some functions. I'm looking for a $q.when, $q.defer, Defer.resolve() and Defer.promise replacement. How to achieve this using Observable?

```
common.$q.when(checkDuplicate()).then(function (dupSc) {
 if(dupsc.length !== 0){
  some functions...
    }}

function checkDuplicate() {
        var defer = common.$q.defer();
        var url = "XYZ"
        dataService.getData(url).then(function (response) {
            defer.resolve(response.value);
        });
        return defer.promise;
    }
```

now I want to convert all this functions to Angular 6 using Observable could anyone suggest the best way to replace this in Angular 6 with the example.

Comment: Yes, you should study observables, since that's what Angular uses to deal with asynchrony (and more).

Comment: @JBNizet I have used Observable in Service for CRUD operation,I couldnt find replacement for above functions used in AngularJs, could you pls give the Example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a one to one comparison. `$q` is essentially an implementation of `Promise`, and since Angular switched to using `RxJs`, there was not a one to one mapping. However, whatever you can do with `$q` is possible in `RxJs` in a slightly different manner.

Since it depends on your design requirements how you want to implement your observables, I won't be able to give examples of all cases, but I recently had to transform my own Angular1 project (using `$q.defer()`) to Angular7 (now using `RxJs` observables), and here is one example.

In angular1, the search functionality was: as user types, call backend to get search data, but cancel that request as soon as user types more, and return the most recent data i.e. just like in google. I was using `defer()` for that.

In angular2, the same functionality can be achieved using [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap). `switchMap` will discard any previous events generated for which results are not yet available with the new event and wait for the new event's results. This is same as resolving the `defer()` promise prematurely. Below is the code for my angular2 search functionality.

```
fromEvent(this.searchTextInput.nativeElement, 'keyup')
  .pipe(
    map((event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      return event.target
    }),
    debounceTime(1000),
    switchMap((searchInput: HTMLInputElement) => {
      this.searchInProgress = true
      this.searchText = searchInput.value

      if (this.searchText.length > 0) {
        return this.pluginService.searchPlugins(searchInput.value)
      } else {
        return EMPTY
      }
    })
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (plugins: Plugin[]) => {
      this.searchInProgress = false
      this.searchResults = plugins
    },
    error: (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      this.searchInProgress = false
      this.errorChange.emit(error)
    }
  })
```